# Loop to create one dataframe from multiple URLs

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, tidyverse

I have a character vector with multiple URLs that each host a csv of crime data for a certain year. Is there an easy way to create a loop that will read.csv and rbind all the dataframes without having to run read.csv 8 times over? The vector of URLs is below

```
urls <- c('https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/73cd2f2858714cd1a7e2859f8e6e4de4_33.csv',
          'https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/fdacfbdda7654e06a161352247d3a2f0_34.csv',
          'https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/9d5485ffae914c5f97047a7dd86e115b_35.csv',
          'https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/010ac88c55b1409bb67c9270c8fc18b5_11.csv',
          'https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/5fa2e43557f7484d89aac9e1e76158c9_10.csv',
          'https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/6eaf3e9713de44d3aa103622d51053b5_9.csv',
          'https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/35034fcb3b36499c84c94c069ab1a966_27.csv',
          'https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/bda20763840448b58f8383bae800a843_26.csv'
          )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `map_dfr` from the `purrr` package does exactly what you want. It applies a function to every element of an input (in this case `urls`) and binds together the result by row.

```
library(tidyverse)
map_dfr(urls, read_csv)
```

I used `read_csv()` instead of `read.csv()` out of personal preference but both will work.

Comment: Does `map_dfr` accept `vectors` as well as `lists`?

Comment: @Sotos The `purrr` package has so many awesome tools, I feel like I'm just scratching the surface.

Comment: @ChiPak Yes indeed, in my example `urls` is a vector.

Answer (score 3):

In base R:

```
result <- lapply(urls, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
result <- do.call(rbind, result)
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually take this approach as I want to save all the csv files separately in case later I need to do further analysis on each of them. Otherwise, you don't need a for-loop.

```
for (i in 1:length(urls)) assign(paste0("mycsv-",i), read.csv(url(urls[i]), header = T))

df.list <- mget(ls(pattern = "mycsv-*"))

#use plyr if different column names and need to know which row comes from which csv file
library(plyr)
df <- ldply(df.list) #you can remove first column if you wish

#Alternative solution in base R instead of using plyr
#if they have same column names and you only want rbind then you can do this:
df <- do.call("rbind", df.list)
```